# Querying db for a list of records using mybatis causes: An unexpected token "IN" was found following

Tags: java, sql, mybatis

Any idea what might be wrong with mybatis mapper?

Manually running this SQL, I get expected results ..

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID = '304ed0ea-07c1-4261-bb0f-b44036f285e6' AND RUN_ID IN ('be7e0d61-bdb4-4341-ab35-fd5007e99e58');
```

And the SQL looks the same in my mapper xml ..

```
<select id="selectByIdAndRunIds" parameterType="java.util.HashMap" resultMap="result">
  SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
  WHERE ID = #{id} AND RUN_ID IN
  <foreach item="item" collection="runIds" open="(" separator="," close=")">
      #{item}
  </foreach>
</select>
```

The Java ..

```
public List<SomeObject> selectByIdAndRunIds(final String id, final List<String> runIds) {
    SqlSession session = MyBatisSqlSession.getInstance().getSqlSessionFactory().openSession(true);

    Map<String, Object> input = new HashMap<>();
    input.put("id", id);
    input.put("runIds", runIds);

    List<SomeObject> result = session.selectList("selectByIdAndRunIds", input);

    session.close();
    return result;
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
### Error querying database.
Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: 
An unexpected token "IN" was found following "= ? AND RUN_ID".  
Expected tokens may include:  "<boolean_factor>".. 
SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.24.92
```

Comment: where you define batchId\flowIds ?

Comment: @MangeshAuti That was a typo, should be `id` and `runId`

Comment: looks all ok ,might be runIds is empty .check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`runIds` was an empty list i.e `runIds.size() == 0`.

Added logic to not execute the query if `runIds.size() == 0`